# Bash prompt display username starting with $

Tags: linux, bash

I have registered some linux machines intro AD with sssd and it works great, but I have an issue with the bash prompt. Some AD usernames start with $ and the prompt refuses to display it, so now I'm left with the string similar to `@servername:~$`

If I do an `export PS1="\$USER@\H"` it gets displayed correctly.

Any ideas on how to make bash prompt either escape the special character, or make sssd edit the bashrc with the "correct" format?

Comment: Are you sure the user name starts with `$`? That's an illegal user name character [according to POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437), which allows only [these characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) (alphanumeric and `.`, `_` or `-`, also first letter not `-`). I think some OSs don't _refuse_ other characters (eg. for `adduser(1)`), but a leading `$` is bound to cause problems. What is the output of `id -un` as one of these users?

Comment: @dan yes, I'm sure. Those users come from AD

Comment: So AD is Active Directory? You should tag the question `active-directory`. It sounds like the proper solution is: "SSSD can use the SID of an AD user to algorithmically generate POSIX IDs in a process called ID mapping. ID mapping creates a map between SIDs in AD and IDs on Linux." from [red hat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/sssd-integration-intro).

Comment: I'm confused, you have a solution, you know you need to put the solution into .bashrc, but you don't want to put it in bashrc.... you want sssd to change bashrc? Why???

Comment: @xpusostomos I don't know a way to put that on bashrc automatically, as new AD users come an log into new machines and sssd creates the homefolder on first login.

Comment: So what I understand is, you want a configuration to apply to all users... even  people who've never edited their ~/.bashrc.  For this you need to make your changes to /etc/bashrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a Linux configuration question and would work better in [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), but generally to change default user configuration you'd want to edit the files in `/etc/skel`.